# Openerp: How to cancel a po even if the incoming shipment is in done state

Tags: odoo

So I have a po which has a incoming shipment in the done state.
The user tried to return it. The delivery order was made but they cancelled it.

Now I am not sure how I can return the goods and cancel the po.

Please advice.

Thank you,
Vishal Khialani